# Append Text in TextBox in C# using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can i add a text value in the textbox with the previous value (just append new value with old value.without removing) in Jquery

Comment: what is the id of textbox??? and did you use master page for current page??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var oldVal = $('#textbox-id').val();
var newVal = "new value";
$('#textbox-id').val(oldVal + newVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#textboxId").val($("#textboxId").val() + "addition");
```

Answer (score 0):

To append the the contents to existing textbox,Use.

```
$('#txtboxID').val($('#txtboxID').val()+"some txt")
```

Just in case if you have used Master page:

```
var txtbox= '<%=txtboxID.ClientID %>';
$('#'+txtbox).val($('#'+txtbox).val()+"some txt")
```